# Is there an option for mysql as dialect while generating queries for TPC-DS?

Tags: mysql, benchmarking, tpc

I have loaded the data and everything is set. But the dialects available are db2, oracle, sqlserver, ansi and netezza. None of these are fully compatible with mysql. Is there a way to generate the queries for mysql?

Comment: I would be surprised.  Although I'm not intimately familiar with TPC-DS, I would expect it to make use of window/analytic functions, which are not available in MySQL.

Comment: The queries are in sql, but constructs like top N and with VAR as (select ...) etc. are not suppoerted in mysql. One can edit the queries manually, but I was looking for a better way.

Comment: `top` is specific to SQL Server.  `with` is a standard construct as are window functions.  MySQL functionality is sufficiently different from ANSI standard that it can be hard to implement "standard" queries.  Admittedly, other databases have differences, but these tend to be more like `substr()` versus `substring()`.